# Can I instruct all incoming arrows of one state to land at its top?

Tags: plantuml

For PlantUML state diagram, is there a way I can have all the inputs to one state coming to the state at the top of the state?

For example, for the following:

```
@startuml

skin rose

title Simple State Model
[*] --> GlassEmpty
GlassEmpty --> [*]
GlassEmpty : Contents - void

GlassEmpty -> GlassFull
GlassFull : Water
GlassFull --> [*]

state1 -> GlassFull


@enduml
```

How can I have the arrows from state1 and GlassEmpty land at the top of GlassFull?

**Update**: figured out, adding "down" in the middle of the dash dash positions the arrow:

```
@startuml

skin rose

title Simple State Model
[*] --> GlassEmpty
GlassEmpty --> [*]
GlassEmpty : Contents - void

GlassEmpty -down-> GlassFull
GlassFull : Water
GlassFull --> [*]

state1 -down-> GlassFull


@enduml
```